# Why can't I ~UPDATE Table SET Field=NULL WHERE 1=1~ in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, null, sql-update

I'm trying this in Google BigQuery

```
UPDATE table 
SET field = NULL 
WHERE 1=1
```

and getting this error: "Cannot set write disposition in jobs with DML statements".

How can I achieve the same effect?

6/3 update: My settings look like this. Still giving me the same error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this DML in BigQuery Console UI - make sure you don't have destination table set - check Options panel

Same recommendation if you run it via API, bq or any other client - make sure you don't set destination table!

Comment: Are you talking about this option? (I added a photo to my post at the bottom)

Comment: Yes. this usually a reason for error like yours